# Codeigniter error 404 on production after set_flashdata

Tags: codeigniter, session

I'm using CI on my project, when I moved it on production server, I saw the error "404 page not found" when calling $this->session->set_flashdata. This error is preserved when I requested any page until I cleared the cookies. This error repeats after call "set_flashdata" again.

```
function _set_success($message)
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('is_db_msg', 1);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('db_msg', $message);;
}

$result = $this->page_model->edit_page($page_name, $this->_get_data_array());

$result ? $this->_set_success('OK') : $this->_set_error(DB_ERROR);

redirect(BASEURL.'admin/pages');
```

// server 404 (on any page) after redirect

BASEURL it's constant: DEFINE('http://mysite.com');
Also I'm using this .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php/?)?(.*[^/])/?$ http://mysite.com/$2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mysite.com [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(index\.php/?)?(.+)/$ /$2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_FINISH} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301]


RewriteRule ^(main/index(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(system|application).*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,E=FINISH:END] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,E=FINISH:END]
```

Please, help and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: `BASEURL` is quiet unknown to me. is that an alias of `base_url()` helper?

Comment: No, it's constant DEFINE('BASEURL','http://mysite.com')

Comment: Of course that it is. I mean why do you need a handy constant to locate your URL? why not to use CI built-in helpers?

Comment: You should try redirect('admin/pages') instead of redirect(BASEURL.'admin/pages');

Answer (score 0):

```
You should use following for redirecting:

redirect('admin/pages');

or

redirect(base_url().'index.php/admin/pages');

or

DEFINE('BASEURL','http://mysite.com')
redirect(BASEURL.'index.php/admin/pages');
```